# SharePoint Project Tasks - displaying gantt

Tags: tasks

I have a list with template of Project Tasks, I have a number of summary tasks and inside these a number of tasks.

I'd like to create a page which displays the gantt view (as it is after I clicked on a summary task) but grouped by Summary Task... or even overlayed.

Is this possible with out-of-the-box features?